# How do you find the general solution of the ordinary differential equation $\frac{dT}{dt}+ \frac{1}{5} T-3=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been asked to find the general solution of the equation 
$$\dfrac{dT}{dt}+ \frac{1}{5} T-3=0$$
Can someone please guide me to the steps on how to do this? I am unsure.

Comment: do what @mfl says and then integrate it.. (this procedure is most commonly known by the name: separation of variables thu..)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: One way is to introduce a new variable, $T' = T-15$. This will leave the derivative of the same form and get rid of the 3, which I guess is what is causing you trouble...

Comment: where did you get that T-15 from? this is very confusing sorry

Comment: sorry should have maybe explained that... $T/5 - 3 = (1/5)(T-15)$